# Moving sum in SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

EDIT: the server I'm working on is 2008 R2 but my client is 2012...

I'm trying to create a conditionnal sum based on the month I'm in backing up to one year ago.
Here is the data I have:

```
Month   Location    Quantity1   Quantity2
200501  2072        46          42
200502  2072        53          51
200503  2072        141         132
200504  2072        134         129
200505  2072        75          72
200506  2072        75          74
200507  2072        77          72
200508  2072        56          52
200509  2072        58          54
200510  2072        59          52
200511  2072        71          69
200512  2072        48          46
200601  2072        62          55
200602  2072        209         197
200603  2072        143         138
200604  2072        78          67
200605  2072        95          86
200606  2072        78          73
200607  2072        80          73
200608  2072        68          62
200609  2072        54          46
200610  2072        52          49
200611  2072        50          50
200612  2072        28          27
```

so, what I would like as an output is something like this:
for the first month(200501) only it can be in the total as there were no records prior to it, up to 200512 it would be between the starting month (200501) and the month in question. Once it goes to 200601, it has to be a sum between 200502 and 200601.

I did the mannual calculations to help the validation process, so here they are:

```
 Month   Location   SumQty1     SumQty2
 200501  2072        46          42
 200502  2072        99          93
 200503  2072        240         225
 200504  2072        374         354
 200505  2072        449         426
 200506  2072        524         500
 200507  2072        601         572
 200508  2072        657         624
 200509  2072        715         678
 200510  2072        774         730
 200511  2072        845         799
 200512  2072        893         845
 200601  2072        909         858
 200602  2072        1065        1004
 200603  2072        1067        1010
 200604  2072        1011        948
 200605  2072        1031        962
 200606  2072        1034        961
 200607  2072        1037        962
 200608  2072        1049        972
 200609  2072        1045        964
 200610  2072        1038        961
 200611  2072        1017        942
 200612  2072        997         923
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: which version of Sql Server? Later versions have Windowing functions that make this kind of thing quite easy.

Comment: What part of it are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the table to itself to get all dates that need to be added:

```
SELECT  t1.Month ,
        t1.Location ,
        SUM(t2.Quantity1) AS SumQty1 ,
        SUM(t2.Quantity2) AS SumQty2
FROM    dbname.schemaname.tablename t1
        INNER JOIN dbname.schemaname.tablename t2 ON t2.month >= t1.month - 99
                                                     AND t2.month <= t1.month
GROUP BY t1.month ,
        t1.location
```

Comment: Simple, great answer!!

Comment: Thank you Dave, took a while to make it work, but that was a mistake on my part!

Answer (score 0):

Try windowing functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
SELECT Month, Location, 
  SUM(Quantity1) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY Month ROWS 11 preceding) as SumQty1,
  SUM(Quantity2) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY Month ROWS 11 preceding) as SumQty2
FROM 
  (SELECT 200501 as Month, 2072 as Location, 46 as Quantity1, 42 as Quantity2
  UNION SELECT 200502, 2072, 53, 51
  UNION SELECT 200503, 2072, 141, 132
  ...) as t;
```

Although note that this will only work if there are no missing months.

Comment: Great suggestion, unfortunately, I found out the server I'm working on at the moment is in fact a 2008 R2, so it appears I cannot use the ROWS or RANGE arguments...